# Shemona Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since 1841, the year the first Jew was
>   elected to Congress, until the
>   congressional elections of November
>   2010, **198 Jewish men and women** have
>   served in the House or Senate.

http://www.jweekly.com/article/full/60553/jews-on-the-hill-get-their-due-in-fascinating-new-book/

Comment: I wonder whether the book described by the linked-to article includes its definition of "Jewish".

Comment: do not know. however still interesting in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Gematria of "צחק" - "laughter" ([Gen. 21](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0121.htm): 6).

Comment: A word that is close to my heart!

Answer (score 0):

> The 1929 Palestine riots, also known
>   as the Western Wall Uprising, the 1929
>   Massacres (Tarpat in Hebrew), or the
>   Buraq Uprising, refers to a series of
>   demonstrations and riots in late
>   August 1929 when a long-running
>   dispute between Muslims and Jews over
>   access to the Western Wall in
>   Jerusalem escalated into violence.
>   During the week of riots 116 Arabs and
>   133 Jews were killed and 232 Arabs and
>   **198 Jews** were injured and treated in
>   hospital.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1929_Palestine_riots